# Part of code as template argument

Tags: c++, templates

We all know, what is template. Strongly speaking, it is a part of code which is checked for errors only when a copy of it was used and all the arguments where set.

We also know, that the arguments of template must be constant-value expressions. So we cant use variables as the arguments for the template.

But we can see that when template is compiled, the code responsible for it is like copied with the arguments pasted on formal parameters.

Can we use a part of a code as an argument of a template?

For example we have:

```
template<bool arg>
class foo
{
 bool val;
public:
 foo() : val(arg) {};
}
```

Everething is ok, thats works well as `arg` is an constant value.
But, I want't to use a static part of code, pasted to the template like this:

```
class foo
{
    int a,b,c;
public:
    foo() : a(0),b(0),c(0)
    {};
    foo(int an, int bn, int cn) : a(an),b(bn),c(cn)
    {};
    template<partOfCode cond>
    bool foo_check()
    {
        if(cond) return true;
        else return false;
    };
};

int main(char* args, char** argv)
{
    foo foovar;
    foovar.foo_check<this->a==0>();
    //or
    foovar.foo_check<a==3>();
};
```

Of course I get the errors trying to do like this. But if really paste a part of argument code to the template on its place, there will be no any syntax errors at least.

Somebody can answer, that I can use define directive. But that will not help, as template and preprocessor are independent.

Is there a way to implement something like this?

Comment: You are trying *way* too hard. Things like `if(cond) return true;  else return false;` can also be written as `return cond;` and doesn't need a function.

Comment: The compiler will also think that `foo_check<this->` is a complete template expansion, and then wonder what the rest of the line does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates don't copy text like macros do, so you're:

1. trying to reference `this` in non-member function
2. trying to access inaccessible variable
3. trying to instantiate template with run-time value instead of compile-time constant

You'll have to pass a function:

```
template <typename FunctionToCall>
bool foo_check(FunctionToCall func)
{
    return func(); // simplified
};

// this is how you call it with lambda function
foovar.foo_check([&]{ return foovar.get_a() == 0; }); // still have to provide an accessor, or make a friend function instead
```

The hell with the template, if you need just function for a condition, you can do

```
bool foo_check(std::function<bool()> const& func)
{
    return func(); // at this point, isn't foo_check useless?
}
```